# Difference between html construction rules

Tags: html

The whatwg specification has a 12 chapter in one of which the following is written ([12.1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#writing)):

> This section only applies to documents, authoring tools, and markup generators. In particular, it does not apply to conformance checkers; the next section ("parsing HTML documents")

---

> 12.1.2.1 **Start tags**
>
> Start tags must have the following format:
>
> 1. The first character of a start tag must be a U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN character (<).
> 2. The next few characters of a start tag must be the element's tag name.
> 3. If there are to be any attributes in the next step, there must first be one or more ASCII whitespace.
> 4. Then, the start tag may have a number of attributes, the syntax for which is described below. Attributes must be separated from each other by one or more ASCII whitespace.
> 5. After the attributes, or after the tag name if there are no attributes, there may be one or more ASCII whitespace. (Some attributes are required to be followed by a space. See the attributes section below.) Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/).
> 6. This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.
> 7. Finally, start tags must be closed by a U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN character (>).

And there is another sub-chapter in the same section that says ([12.2](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing)):

> This section only applies to user agents, data mining tools, and conformance checkers.

---

> 12.2.5.6 **Tag open state**
>
> Consume the next input character:
>
> - **U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK (!)**
>
>   Switch to the markup declaration open    state.
> - **U+002F SOLIDUS (/)**
>
>   Switch to the end tag open state. ASCII alpha    Create a new start
>   tag token, set its tag name to the empty string.    Reconsume in the
>   tag name state.
> - **U+003F QUESTION MARK (?)**
>
>   This is an    unexpected-question-mark-instead-of-tag-name parse
>   error. Create a    comment token whose data is the empty string.
>   Reconsume in the bogus    comment state.
> - **EOF**
>
>   This is an eof-before-tag-name parse error. Emit a U+003C
>   LESS-THAN SIGN character token and an end-of-file token.
> - **Anything else**
>
>   This is an invalid-first-character-of-tag-name parse    error. Emit
>   a U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN character token. Reconsume in the    data
>   state.

Explain to me the difference. Because in these chapters there are rules for constructing a tag.

Comment: These are not two rule sets to **construct** HTML, only the first one is such. The second one explains how to read that HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between section 12.1 that applies to *documents, authoring tools, and markup generators* (writers) and the section 12.2 that applies to *user agents, data mining tools, and conformance checkers* (readers), comes from the [**robustness principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle):

> Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others (often reworded as "Be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept").

Answer (score 1):

The first set of material you quoted describes the format of a start tag.

The second set of material you quoted describes what a parser should do when consuming the character that follows a `<` that was somewhere that a tag could appear.

Comment: Read the second point (12.1.2.1), it does not exactly describe the name of the tag, it says that the tag should be ASCII aplhanumeric, but we can write the `<container?1>` tag and everything will be correct. The browser will correctly understand this writing, however such tag does not correspond to ASCII alphanumeric. Do not you see a contradiction?

Comment: @MaximPro — There is no contraction between having rules for what a tag name should be, and having rules for how a parser should react to an invalid tag name.

Comment: Wait for the rule of the tag definition that the tag name must be ASCII aplhanumerics i.e pattern `[a-z0-9]`. What does not specify what should be the first character and what subsequent - this creates an inaccuracy. That is, considering this rule, we can think that it's perfectly correct to write `<98car> `- but it will not be true and the browser will process it in a special way.

Comment: "What does not specify what should be the first character and what subsequent" — The specification does specify that. Just not in the section you quoted.

Comment: "the browser will process it in a special way" — Error handling rules do exist in the guide to building a parser that you quoted from. This is so that different HTML parsers generate the same results when given bad input by authors who think it is a good idea to write `<98car>` in their source code.

Comment: So this is a general rule? Which is more accurately described in 10.2? Right? But what about https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name

Comment: @MaximPro — Wrong. One is for how to write start tags in general. The other is about how to read tags in general.

Comment: What does it mean *how to read tags in general*. I do not understand.

Comment: Shouldn't the rule be one for everyone, for concrete describe. I do not understand the difference between reading and writing. Explain more so that I understand the difference.

Comment: @MaximPro — I have already explained multiple times, in different ways, in excruciating detail.

Comment: Could you join the chat I called you to?

Comment: @MaximPro — I could, but I won't. I've explained it in three different ways already. Going to a chat to try to explain it in some more different ways does not seem like a worthwhile use of my time.

Comment: At least read what I wrote there. I do not make you waste your time.